# При использовании while в расчетах не используются очень большие числа но переполнение

Tags: sql-server

Знаете, я решил попробовать написать SQL-функцию для высчитывания банковских процентов. Чтобы можно было ввести в нее сумму вклада и узнать, какова будет сумма этого вклада через несколько лет. Написал  вот какой код:

```
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    --<@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Data_Type_For_Param1, , int>
    --@Dep decimal
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(38,20)

AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE  @Deposit DECIMAL(38,20)
    SET @Deposit=20.0
    DECLARE @Val int
    SET @Val=0

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    --SELECT <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result> = <@Param1, sysname, @p1>
    WHILE(@Val<=3)
    --PRINT 'Inside WHILE LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
    SET @Deposit=@Deposit*1.1
    SET @Val=@Val+1

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Deposit

END
```

И выскочила у меня вот такая  ошибка.

> Ошибка арифметического переполнения при преобразовании numeric к типу
>   данных numeric.

Вся информация, которую я смог найти в Интернете, говорила о том, что такая ошибка возникает,  когда результат вычислений требует слишком большого количества знаков для отображения,  или  слишком большого количества знаков после запятой, И что для ликвидации этой проблемы нужно увеличить числа в параметрах DECIMAL. Но у меня  20 умножается на 1.1 всего 3 раза , и результат должен быть всего 26.620 . Тогда я подумал- "Может быть, у меня  все-таки с самим while  проблемы?(Вообще, по-настоящему толковую информацию о while в SQL оказалось трудно найти.)." .Чтобы выяснить, работает ли мой  while  в принципе , написал вот какой код:

```
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    --<@Param1, sysname, @p1> <Data_Type_For_Param1, , int>
    --@Dep decimal
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE  @Deposit int
    SET @Deposit=2
    DECLARE @Val int
    SET @Val=0

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    --SELECT <@ResultVar, sysname, @Result> = <@Param1, sysname, @p1>
    WHILE(@Val<=3)
    --PRINT 'Inside WHILE LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
    SET @Deposit=@Deposit*2
    SET @Val=@Val+1

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Val
```

И выскочила у меня такая  ошибка:

> Ошибка арифметического переполнения при преобразовании expression к
>   типу данных int.

Короче говоря, я буду рад, если вы объясните мне, в чем моя  проблема, или хотя бы дадите мне пусть самый-самый примитивный ,но работающий пример использования  while  при расчетах. Также буду благодарен, если вы подскажете какой-нибудь другой способ для создания программы для подсчета процентов по банковским вкладам.

Comment: У вас цикл до упора крутится, в `begin ... end` тело цикла оберните.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае проблема в том, что при отсутствии пары BEGIN/END, WHILE выполняет в теле цикла только один оператор

```
WHILE(@Val<=3)
  SET @Deposit=@Deposit*1.1
```

а изменение Val

```
SET @Val=@Val+1
```

находится уже за циклом.

Получается, что переменная в условии не меняется, условие выхода из цикла никогда не достигается, а цикл - бесконечный.

Нужно обернуть в BEGIN/END

```
WHILE(@Val<=3)
BEGIN
  --PRINT 'Inside WHILE LOOP on TechOnTheNet.com';
  SET @Deposit=@Deposit*1.1
  SET @Val=@Val+1
END
```

Единственно, что еще следует добавить, что для того чтобы в результате получилось упомянутое в вопросе число `26.620` (Точнее,  с большим количеством нулей, но это уже частности, зависящие от параметра второго DECIMAL. ), в условии WHILE нужно поставить не `@Val<=3`,  а `@Val<=2`. В SQL первый шаг цикла совершается  еще до того, как меняется переменная  @Val благодаря счетчику.